# Can a ray of light deviate passing from a rarer to a denser medium deviate beyond the normal?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction

[image]

Is this allowed? Technically, if the difference in the refractive indexes is big enough, and the ray of light has a low wavelength (violet), it should be able to deviate beyond the normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this kind of refraction will not occur due to a high refractive index. Snell's law tells us that

$$ n_1 \sin \theta_1 = n_2 \sin \theta_2 $$

where both angles are measured counterclockwise from the normal (or both are measured clockwise; the sign convention is arbitrary). If passing from air $n_1 \approx 1$ to a material with a very high refractive index, then because $n_2$ is so large relative to $n_1$, $\sin \theta_2$ must be very small relative to $\sin \theta_1$, but *still of the same sign*, so the refracted ray will still be on the opposite side of the normal from the incident ray; it'll just be much closer to the normal than the incident ray was.

In order to get the incident and refracted rays on the same side of the normal, you have to pass from a material with positive refractive index to one with negative refractive index or vice versa. [Materials with negative refractive index do not occur in nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative-index_metamaterial), but can be made in the lab.